# Recommended gitignore file for WPF app in Visual Studio project

Tags: git, visual-studio, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm currently using [this gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore) file in a `WPF` app in `Visual Studio Community 2022`, but I'm still getting a bunch of annoying files listed in the Unstaged files in `Sourcetree`.

Any idea how can I prevent the files below from showing in the Unstaged files area in Sourcetree?

This is what I see in the Unstaged files section in Sourctree:

```
AppName/bin/Release/AppName.exe
AppName/bin/Release/AppName.odb
AppName/obj/Debug/DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache
AppName/obj/Debug/AppName.exe
AppName/obj/Debug/AppName.g.resources
AppName/obj/Debug/AppName.pdb
AppName/obj/Debug/AppName MarkupCompile.cache
AppName/obj/Release/DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache
AppName/obj/Release/AppName.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
AppName/obj/Release/AppName.exe
AppName/obi/Release/AppName.g.resources
AppName/obj/Release/AppName.pdb
AppName/obi/Release/Views/SomeView.bam|
AppName/bin/Debug/btest1
AppName/bin/Debug/btest2
AppName/bin/Debug/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll
AppName/bin/Debug/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.dll
AppName/bin/Debug/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.pdb
AppName/bin/Debug/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.pdb
AppName/bin/Debug/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform.dll
AppName/bin/Debug/GalaSoft.MwvmLight.Platform.pdb
AppName/bin/Debug/GalaSoft.MwvmLight.Platform.xml
AppName/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll
AppName/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.pdb
AppName/bin/Debug/System.Windows.Interactivity.dll
AppName/bin/Debug/AppName.exe
AppName/bin/Debug/AppName.exe.CodeAnalysisLog (UserName-PC's conflicted copy 2017-11-06).xml
AppName/bin/Debug/AppName.exe.CodeAnalysisLog.xml
AppName/bin/Debug/AppName.exe.config
AppName/bin/Debug/AppName.exe.lastcodeanalysissucceeded
AppName/bin/Debug/AppName.pdb
AppName/bin/Debug/AppName.vshost.exe
AppName/bin/Debug/AppName.vshost.exe.config
AppName/bin/Debug/AppName.vshost.exe.manifest
AppName/bin/Release/AppName.vshost.exe
AppName/bin/Release/AppName.vshost.exe.config
AppName/bin/Release/AppName.vshost.exe.manifest
```

#### Git Location:

[image]

### EDIT:

Added git location image.

Comment: This gitignore file has been battle tested and is working well and should ignore bin and obj folder. I don't know well source tree and the notion behind 'unstaged' in it but I think that is because file are tracked because already committed before you used a gitignore file. You need to untrack them so that gitignore takes effect on these files.

Comment: You're probably right, these files were already tracked when I started using the .gitignore file since I untracked the files and now everything seems to be working, the files no longer show up. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I mimicked your folder structure on my PC in a new repo, and that `.gitignore` works for me.

I would suggest checking that the `.gitignore` is saved at the root of your repository (though you can have them in sub-folders if you have a specific purpose) and making sure that you've actually saved the file. You can try restarting SourceTree, or go to the command line and run `git status` to see if the files are showing up there too.

Comment: Thank you for the good advice, would you mind checking the image I posted in my original post to see if I have the file in the right location?

Comment: @fs_tigre It looks like it's in the correct location. I'm assuming it's the root of your repo because of the `.git` folder.

Comment: Also, be sure it's saved as ascii / utf-8.

Comment: Thank you all for the good advice. Untracking the files as Philippe suggested seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize they were already tracked. Yeah, that's something that's tripped me up before.